# how to initiate phone number on intl phone number package

Tags: flutter

i have a string got it from database for example "+96170123456"

but the phone number in not always like above, it is international,

so how to put it in intl phone number

```
phoneNbr = "+96170123456";
PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNbr, isoCode: 'LB');
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
            onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                print(number.phoneNumber);
            },
            onInputValidated: (bool value) {
                print(value);
            },
            ignoreBlank: false,
            initialValue: number,
        )
```

i use `intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2`

so how to know the iso code programatically?? what do u suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber` method to check that this phone number is a valid number or not.

```
    try {
        var phoneNumber = "+234 500 500 5005";
        PhoneNumber number = await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

        InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                    print(number.phoneNumber);
                },
                onInputValidated: (bool value) {
                    print(value);
                },
                ignoreBlank: false,
                initialValue: number,
      );
    } catch(e) {
      log("This phone number is not a valid number");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want cause the question is not yet clear to me but I think this should work

Use this in the initState:

```
final List<Locale> systemLocales=WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locales;
String? isoCountryCode = systemLocales.first.countryCode;
```

or you can use this other one but in the Build context:

```
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
print(myLocale.countryCode);
```

This will get the country code and you can add it like this:

```
PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNbr, isoCode: '${myLocale.countryCode}');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify what is stored in the database... then the easiest solution I could come up with is to store the `countryDialCode` also.

Then you can easily get the `initialValue` by removing the country dial code.

```
String phoneNumber = "+96170123456"; // from database
String countryDialCode = '961';      // from database

String number = phoneNumber.replaceFirst('+${countryDialCode}', '');
```

This will give you `number = 70123456` which will now appear as the initial value.

Incase it still does not appear - try using a `TextEditingController` instead of `initialValue`.

For anyone else reading and If I understand correctly - the issue is that if you try to place `+96170123456` as the initial value, nothing will appear as this string contains the country code. So the country code needs to be removed but it's hard to do so without knowing which country the number belongs to.